# Create instance in a sequelize belongs-to-many relation

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, graphql

I'm having trouble to understand sequelize documentation concerning Belongs-to-Many relations. I've been able to set it up properly in the DB itself, but now that I want to perform basic CRUD operation, I'm quite lost.

So here's the thing: I have Users and Chatrooms. Whenever a user creates a chatroom, I want it to be the owner of the room, as well as a participant.

Problem is...I can't figure how to add this user to the participant. DB-wise, there's a chatroom_user table which contains users IDs and chatroom IDs. 
From what I understood from the sequelize documentation, I have to create an addXXXXX function in my model, add call it in the resolver with the wanted args...but this doesn't work...

here's my code

chatroom model:

```
export default (sequelize, Datatypes) => {
    const Chatroom = sequelize.define('chatroom', {
        publicRoom: {
            type: Datatypes.BOOLEAN,
            allowNull: false
        },
    });

    Chatroom.associate = (models) => {
        Chatroom.belongsTo(models.user, {
            foreignKey: {
                name: 'owner',
                allowNull: false
            }
        });
        Chatroom.belongsToMany(models.user, {
            through: 'user_chatroom',
            foreignKey: {
                name: 'chatroom',
                allowNull: false
            },
            onDelete: 'CASCADE'
        });
        Chatroom.addUsers(models.user);
    };
```

chatroom resolvers:

```
export default {
    Query: {
        // some queries here...
    },
    Mutation: {
        createChatroom: async (parent, args, {models, user}, info) => {
            try {
                return await models.chatroom.create({owner: user.id})
                    .then(models.chatroom.addUsers(user.id));
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        },

    }
};
```

So Yeah, I know this is definitely not the way to do it, but I searched many tutorials and found no working solutions... :(

Comment: Why dont you move the logic of owner to the chatroom_user table and add a new column with owner as Boolean?

Comment: the "owner" is not in the chatroom_user table. There are only user's ID and chatroom IDs in it. The owner is a column containing user IDs in the "chatroom" table

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you the following, remove the owner from chatroom and move the owner to the join table, in your case, the chatroom_user table.

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const Chatroom = sequelize.define('chatroom', {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    publicRoom: {
        type: Datatypes.BOOLEAN,
        allowNull: false
    },
  });

  Chatroom.associate = (models) => {
    Chatroom.belongsToMany(models.User, {
      through: 'user_chatroom',
      foreignKey: {
        name: 'userId',
        field: 'user_id',
      },
    });
  };
  return Chatroom;
};
```

then in your UserChatroom Table

```
 export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  const UserChatroom = sequelize.define('user_chatroom', {
    owner: {
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValues: false,
    },
  });

  return UserChatroom;
};
```

and then in your resolver when your create ChatRoom, update the join table user_chatroom with an additional column `owner` with a value true if the user is owner of the chatroom or false it its not

some thing like this

```
id| owner | user_id|chatroom_id|
1 | false | 1      | 1         |
2 | true  | 2      | 1         |
3 | false | 3      | 1         |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Javed for taking from your time to reply to me :) However I think I may have not be clear enough. My problem is not really the owner field (still, thanks for sharing your solution, that might be  handy, indeed). My problem is about writing my whole createChatroom mutation. The current code I wrote crashes (which don't really surprises me, since I have no idea of what I'm doing...) . The room creation works, but the second part where it should assign my current user to the current chatroom in the join table, fails. And that is my main question ;)

Comment: If your association is correct, you shouldn't need to do it manually, could you check what data is being updated in the table?

Comment: I tried with your new code. Something I noticed is that you created a new model for UserChatroom. At first, I thought it was the chatroom model.... Now, if I leave the .then() funtion, it crashes saying that models.chatroom.addUser is not a function. If I remove it, it tries to perform the following SQL operation: Executing (default): INSERT INTO "chatrooms" ("id","created_at","updated_at") VALUES (DEFAULT,'2018-09-17 13:51:46.240 +00:00','2018-09-17 13:51:46.240 +00:00') RETURNING *;